# How to add third-party script code into our magento2 for Website tracking

Tags: admin, magento2.2.4

how to add third-party script code into our magento2 for website tracking. I don't know how to implement this task. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Just add your third party script from admin in that section.

admin -> content -> design -> configuration ->  edit ( click on link which one your current theme) -> script and style sheets

[image]

Comment: Hi @ Ansar Husain, How to add Facebook script code with my product details in magento2?

Comment: use this module then https://marketplace.magento.com/apptrian-facebook-pixel.html